# Regular Expression in JavaScript to Parse a UM String

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a function that returns a unit of measure string such as:
Barrel [US, Liquid] [BBL]
I want a regular expression that works with a JavaScript string method and either returns or modifies the string into these two options:

a) get the abbreviation (e.g. BBL)

b) get the full name (e.g. Barrel [US, Liquid])

For the abbreviation I already had tried `string.match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1]`, which works for most of the other UMs (like Bank Cubic Meter [BCm]) but breaks on the example I have above, returning US, Liquid] [BBL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use

```
string.replace(/\[[^\[\]]*]$/, "")
```

to get rid of the abbreviation and the brackets around it.

To get the abbreviation use

```
string.match(/\[[^\[\]]*]$/)[0]
```

which will return the abbreviation surrounded by the brackets. Then use

```
string.match(/\w+/)[0]
```

to get the abbreviation from inside the brackets. (This assumes that your abbreviation are made of word characters (letters, numbers, and underscores)). If your abbreviation contains other characters this regex will capture everything but brackets.

```
string.match(/[^\[\]]+/)[0]
```

Comment: Good answer. One thing that I felt was worth mentioning is that the match method returns an array, so in order to get the string you need to append [0] to the statement.